# Can I number theorem based on section or subsection, not chapter?

Tags: css, r, bookdown

I typed what I've studied and organized it on the `Github pages` using `R bookdown`. While typing I have to write theorem, but when I uses theorem environment of theorem, it has been written as below:

```
Theorem 8.1
```

However, each chapter is the subject I studied, and the subsection summarizes what I studied in the corresponding week for each subject, so the shape need to be as follows:

```
Theorem 8.1.1.
```

But even though I looked through all the files and settings, I couldn't find a way to modify the corresponding settings. If I make the output into a `pdf`, it uses `latex`, therefore I can change the configuration of theorem numbering, however, I'm currently using `HTML` output for `GitHub pages`, so it seems it can not directly use `latex` configuration and seems only operate through `css`, where I could not find any corresponding configuration.

Is there any way to modify it? Thanks for the help.